# Get users orders list of past N days from firestore in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I want show admin the list of users and there purchases in last N days (say one month). I m storing all the order details in firestore .Here how my database structure looks like [image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCU3v.png) . The id you see (i.e : 1612200564594 ) in orders is simply generated using ***Date().getTime()*** , which is the time of purchase .

Is there a way so that i can query these orders to show them in a table with the fields given in the image above.

For now i m able to just get the orders list from this code

```
var db = firebase.firestore();  
    var docRef = db.collection("orders");
    docRef.orderBy("orders", "desc");

    docRef.get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
            // i can access fields like address, author Phone no. etc
        });
    });
```

Comment: BTW spelling of status and total uploads is wrong in firestore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm putting a reference function. You can take and modify it for your needs.

```
n_days_ago_from_now = (days) => new Date(new Date().getTime() - 1000*60*60*24*days)

n_days_ago_from_now(3)
Date Sat Jan 30 2021 15:42:10 GMT+0400    
n_days_ago_from_now(5)
Date Thu Jan 28 2021 15:42:13 GMT+0400
```

Comment: Thanks , this will work just need to convert into integer format .